# Column parsing in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

One of my excel columns like below.

```
COL A                COL B
----------------------------------------
ABCDEFGH             ABCDEFGH-#648-2011 EXT.8503
```

In column C , I wanted value should be  -#648-2011 EXT.8503

How can I do this in Excel?

I have tried formula like this :

```
=LEFT(B242,LEN(LEFT(A242,LEN(A242))))
```

However, its not working, please suggest?

Comment: You have mistaken right with left and a mistake with the length of A242.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your data it seems that B2 has a value with A2 sticked to the left of it. If this is the case then you could use:

```
=RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-LEN(A2))
```

If this isn't the case and it is just a coincidence, then I agree with @Tim Biegeleisen his answer :)

**EDIT:**

Might you want to exclude the hyphen then use:

```
=RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-LEN(A2)-1)
```

Comment: You need to subtract one more to get rid of the hyphen

Comment: Thanks @Ron Rosenfeld, assuming he needs to exclude the hyphen. I am not sure since in the question at hand it is included in the wanted cell value.

Comment: You are correct.  In the question he does show the hyphen as part of what he wants.  I over looked that.

Comment: @JvdV I was just going to say that

Answer (score 1):

Many solutions:

You could replace the first instance of `A1-` in `B1` with a null string:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B1,A1&"-","",1)
```

or start after a certain location:

```
=MID(B1,LEN(A1)+2,99)
```

If you really want to include the hyphen in the result in column C, then make the minor changes in the formulas above

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B1,A1,"",1) 
=MID(B1,LEN(A1)+1,99)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this formula:

```
=MID(B1, FIND("-", B1), LEN(B1) - FIND("-", B1) + 1)
```

This says to take a substring, starting at the position of the first dash `-`, for the remainder of the string after that starting point.